# OAuth in Meteor with different URL callback for example www. at the start doesn't log in

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth, https

I was playing around with getting a prototype app to log in with Twitter using OAuth and noticed something strange.

It works when I put in eg. http://example.com but when I try logging in to http://www.example.com it pops up and then tries to redirect me to the `ROOT_URL=http://example.com` and in Chrome & Firefox the window just stays locked there. In Safari the window disappears, but I am still logged out.

Is this expected behaviour from a Meteor App or any web app? Would there be any way of getting it to work with `www.` and without? Should I just redirect `www.` requests to use without the `www.`?

I also get similar behaviour when trying **http** and ssl **https**.

Are there any websites out there that use OAuth from different web addresses I guess is what I'm asking? And how do they achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is here. Please provide config information - is it really redirecting to "ROOT_URL=http://example"?

Comment: @Mikkel Sorry that was a typo. I changed it. The test is live at http://twinker.tk you can log in and I set permissions as read only. Then try http://www.twinker.tk and it won't work.